# Replace dot by comma on Json Data content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I'm extracting a percentage data using a json file and displaying it on my web site :

```
<?php
    $resultData = file_get_contents('https://example.com/json/stats?_l=en');
    $jsonData = json_decode($resultData, true);
    if( isset( $jsonData["stats"] ) && !empty($jsonData["stats"]) ){
    
        foreach( $jsonData["stats"] as $stat ){                 
            echo "<div class='stat-item'>".$stat["item_example"]." % My Data displaying here </div>";
        }           
    }
?>
```

I'm trying to replace the "dot" with a "comma" in the displayed percentage. Example replace 5.5 with 5,5

I'm trying to do it with the following Javascript

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.stat-item').keyup(function () {
            var content = $(this).val();
            $(this).val(content.replace(/[\.]+/g, ','));
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Why on `keyup` event?

Comment: try this $(this).val(content.replace(/./g, ',')

Comment: You can use the [`Intl.NumberFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat) to enable language-sensitive number formatting.

Comment: Doesn't look like you're trying to change "json data content" - more than you want to change the html (that was, previously, created from json data, but that's irrelevant at the time of change).

Comment: What's the question/problem here?  You've added some html to a `div` but then used `keyup` / `val` - div's don't take focus unless you make them editable - have you done that? (not in your snippet)  Change `keyup` to `click` to see it in action or just remove the keyup line and `$(".state-item").each(...` on load.  Then your question asks about changing json content, but has code to change html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to build the dom with php and then manipulate it with javascript (btw with the wrong event handler). I'd do it on the php side, using [number_format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

So your php would become:

```
echo "<div class='stat-item'>".number_format($stat["item_example"],2,",",".")." % My Data displaying here </div>";
```

In this example you are limiting to 2 decimal places the numbers returned, you are using `,` as decimal separator instead of the dot you get now, and you are using `.` as the thousands separator (for info only since I don't expect your figures to get higher than 100)

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `val()` but `text()` instead; also is not clear why you need `keyup` event on the `div`. I would just write:

```
$(".stat-item").each(function () {
  var content = $(this).text();
  $(this).text(content.replace(/[\.]+/g, ","));
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried this but it still doesn't work.

Comment: What is not working exactly? You can check here https://codepen.io/dariospadoni/pen/JjRQOmp that the dot is replaced with the , when you execute the code

Comment: it was my mistake. I forgot to declare <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script> Thanks @Dario